# SQL - Aggregate Functions and Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

**MyView:**

```
JobId,
ClientName,
ClientAddress,
Cost
```

**Example data within MyView:**

```
1, John, 23 road, 25
1, John, 23 road, 20
1, John, 23 road, 5
2, James, 6 road, 10
2, James, 6 road, 4
```

I want to SUM the cost for each JobId, but also return the ClientName, ClientAddress, etc..
This view is large, and having to group the ClientName, Client Address is taking a long time to run.

What is the best way to handle this?

**The query I currently have is:**

```
SELECT ClientName,
ClientAddress,
SUM(Cost) as TotalCost
FROM MyView
GROUP BY JobId, ClientName, ClientAddress, TotalCost
```

**Results I'm after:**

```
John, 23 road, 50 
James, 6 road, 14
```

Comment: Show the results you want.

Comment: Results:
John, 23 road, 50
James, 6 road, 14

Comment: Are ClientName and ClientAddress always the same for each JobId?  That is, can a JobId be associated with more than one name and/or address?  Also, must you use the (presumably denormalized) view, or do you have access to the underlying tables?

Comment: @NickStraguzzi ClientName and ClientAddress are always the same.
I do not have access to the underlying tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ClientName and ClientAddress are always the same for every JobID, then this (though kludgy) will work:

```
SELECT MIN(ClientName), MIN(ClientAddress), SUM(Cost) AS TotalCost
  FROM MyView
 GROUP BY JobId
```

Under that assumption, all you really want to group by is JobID, as everything else is either invariant or an aggregation target.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total on each row, you can use window functions:

```
select v.*, sum(cost) over (partition by jobid)
from myview v;
```

Answer (score 0):

If name and address is same for each job id, I think this should work, you should not use totalcost in `group by`

```
SELECT ClientName,
ClientAddress,
SUM(Cost) as TotalCost
FROM MyView
GROUP BY  ClientName, ClientAddress
```